# Router FTP upload

Tags: router, ftp, home-networking, upload

I have a USB drive connected to my hg556a router from Vodafone ([manual](http://goo.gl/XIch8)).  I'm attempting a backup using FTP via wired ethernet -> router -> USB2.0.

On wireless it managed two simultaneous uploads at approximately 80kbps, so I am trying wired instead.  Via a wired connection it can only do one transfer at a time (via wireless it was two - on wired the second attempt in FileZilla continually gets rejected by the router), and it's not much faster at about 120kbps.

Those speeds are not good enough for a network media/backup drive.  I would expect the upload speed to be close to 1Mbps (limited by the ethernet connection).

What can I investigate to improve this upload connection speed, and get the second FTP connection working again via the wired connection?

I'm using Ubuntu on the uploading computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try install a custom firmware such as Openwrt because you can tweak the USB drive's mounting parameters to improve your USB write speed.

I can achieve a few MB/seconds write on my router running Openwrt.

Comment: What tweaks did you make to do that?